# How to write a test for a service that handles redirects

Tags: api, testing

I have created a server that redirects visitors if they have certain parameters in their request e.g.

```
www.myservice.com/1 --> redirects to google.com
www.myservice.com/2 --> redirects to facebook.com
```

How would I write script to automate the testing of this? It can be in any language, I am just interested in the overall concept.

Furthermore, where could I host such a script so that it runs let's say once a day? Perhaps a cron job + a log.txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always test the response came from your **API** once you send a request, these responses must have the information needed (**status code redirect** in your case that tells the client to redirect this user to this **URL**), so you can test that the response came has this status code.

Every language you use has its own testing mechanisms, therefore you can always test this.

Also, tests should be executed at build time of the application and if these tests are executed successfully then you can build your artifacts and publish them.

These tests belong to your project source code and you need to maintain them exactly like production code. As an example for testing frameworks in Java there is `JUnit` which is responsible for writing tests for your production code and there are a lot of frameworks that help you to test your APIs.